# How to make an exception on hide all panels?

Tags: c#

I just saw answer on another question for hiding all panels in form. So i wonder how to make exception to this code. This code is in C#.

> ```
>         foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
>         {
>             if (c is Panel) c.Visible = false;
>         }
> ```

I tried to add another if to check if c is my panel but that does not work.

> if (c is MyPanel) continue;

MyPanl is name of my panel.

Error list say `A constant value is expected`

Can someone help?

Comment: What's `MyPanel` class is that inherit from `Panel`?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Errors? Exceptions? Unexected behaviour? Did you debug the issue to see what´s happening?

Comment: @D-Shih MyPanel is `Object` constructed from class `Panel`

Comment: @HimBromBeere I edited question.

Comment: Could you please show where and how `MyPanel` is declared? It´s not clear if this is the name of a variable or member or if it is a class-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment you can try to use `c == MyPanel` to be the condition instead of `c is MyPanel`  because `... is ...` checked the type instead of compare instance.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c == MyPanel) continue;
    else if  (c is Panel) c.Visible = false;
}
```

I would use linq `where` to set the condition to let the code clearer

```
var panels = this.Controls
    .Cast<Control>()
    .Where(c => c != MyPanel && c is Panel);

foreach (var c in panels)
{
    c.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This helped me much.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic No problem glad to help :)